# Can not acquire write lock on EC2-based Cassandra backend

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, cassandra, janusgraph

I have deployed [Cassandra 3.11.1](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/cassandra/3.11.1/apache-cassandra-3.11.1-bin.tar.gz) on an [EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_AT&sc_publisher=google&sc_medium=english_ec2_b&sc_content=ec2_e&sc_detail=amazon%20ec2&sc_category=ec2&sc_segment=175033903347&sc_matchtype=e&sc_country=AT&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!175033903347!e!!g!!amazon%20ec2&ef_id=VG-FZQAAAIQAbXnD:20180123084915:s) instance and connecting to it from my machine using the [JanusGraph](http://janusgraph.org) Java API. For testing purposes, the instance allows all inbound and outbound TCP connections.

In the `cassandra.yaml` file I have configured the following values like so:

- `listen_address`: *private EC2 address*
- `broadcast_address`: *public EC2 address*
- `seeds`: *public EC2 address*
- `start_rpc: true`
- `rpc_address`: *private EC2 address*
- `endpoint_snitch: Ec2MultiRegionSnitch`

**Note** that when I want to use the *public EC2 address* as `rpc_address`, Cassandra startup fails with this message:

> Failed to bind port 9042 on <*public EC2 address*>

Finally I try to connect to the graph, add a vertex and commit.

```
JanusGraph graph = JanusGraphFactory.build()
        .set("storage.backend", "cassandra")
        .set("storage.hostname", "<public EC2 address>")
        .set("storage.cassandra.keyspace", "debug")
        .set("storage.batch-loading", false)

        .set("query.force-index", false)
        .set("query.fast-property", true)

        .set("cache.db-cache", true)
        .set("schema.default", "default")

        .set("index.search.backend", "elasticsearch")
        .set("index.search.hostname", "127.0.0.1")
        .set("index.search.elasticsearch.interface", "REST_CLIENT")
        .open();

graph.addVertex("myLabel");
graph.tx().commit();
```

Committing fails with the following error:

```
09:41:53.297 [main] ERROR o.j.g.database.StandardJanusGraph - Could not commit transaction [1] due to exception
org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.TemporaryLockingException: Temporary locking failure
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.AbstractLocker.writeLock(AbstractLocker.java:309) ~[janusgraph-core-0.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ExpectedValueCheckingStore.acquireLock(ExpectedValueCheckingStore.java:103) ~[janusgraph-core-0.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.KCVSProxy.acquireLock(KCVSProxy.java:52) ~[janusgraph-core-0.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.BackendTransaction.acquireIndexLock(BackendTransaction.java:256) ~[janusgraph-core-0.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph.prepareCommit(StandardJanusGraph.java:572) ~[janusgraph-core-0.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph.commit(StandardJanusGraph.java:702) ~[janusgraph-core-0.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.StandardJanusGraphTx.commit(StandardJanusGraphTx.java:1374) [janusgraph-core-0.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphBlueprintsGraph$GraphTransaction.doCommit(JanusGraphBlueprintsGraph.java:272) [janusgraph-core-0.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.AbstractTransaction.commit(AbstractTransaction.java:105) [gremlin-core-3.2.6.jar:3.2.6]
    at engineering.divine.core.test.ConnectionTest.test(ConnectionTest.java:29) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Lock write retry count exceeded
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ConsistentKeyLocker.writeSingleLock(ConsistentKeyLocker.java:341) ~[janusgraph-core-0.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ConsistentKeyLocker.writeSingleLock(ConsistentKeyLocker.java:125) ~[janusgraph-core-0.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.AbstractLocker.writeLock(AbstractLocker.java:304) ~[janusgraph-core-0.2.0.jar:na]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
```

I would appreciate any pointers on what could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The network latency between my local machine and the EC2 instance was in fact too high to acquire a lock in time. Increasing the [`storage.lock.wait-time`](http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/config-ref.html#_storage_lock) from 100ms to 1s resolved the issue.